# multiline pattern delete with single line command

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I would like to **delete all empty segments** in my file.

The empty segment can be specified by a pair of consecutive lines starting with `START` and ending with `END`. Valid segments will have some contents between lines starting with START and ending with END

**Sample Input**

```
Header

START arguments
END

Any contents

START arguments
...
something
...
END

Footer
```

**Desired Output**

```
Header


Any contents

START arguments
...
something
...
END

Footer
```

Here I'm looking for possible **one liners**. Any help would be appreciated.

**Trials**

I tried following `awk`. It works to some extent but it deletes START lines even in valid segments.

```
awk '/^START/ && getline && /^END$/ {next} 1' file
```

Comment: That deletes START lines because you don't print them before you getline.

Comment: @EtanReisner I understand that, but if I just print all START lines then even lines in empty segments would be printed. May be I need more conditioning. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need more conditionals then you can get in a pattern statement I believe. See my answer for a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) only

```
awk -v RS='START[^\n]*\nEND\n' '{printf "%s", $0}' file.txt
```

Comment: Wow! different idea, liked it! `'{printf "%s", $0}'` can simply be `'1'` and it would be really short

Comment: @jkshah, using `1` instead of `{printf "%s", $0}` introduces redudant newlines, but then again that may well be fine by you!

Comment: +1 You don't need to escape the backslashes in the RS, though, it gets treated by awk as a constant RE not a string.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -00 -pe 's/START .*?\nEND//g' file
```

this is a better one. 
the solution I gave earlier will discard whole paragraph if they are not separated by blank lines.

Earlier response below:

how about this perl one liner ?

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if not /START .*\nEND/' file
```

read-in file in paragraph mode and discard lines matching `START <string><newline>END`

Comment: just replace it with a pattern .* if so. `perl -00 -ne 'print if not /START .*\nEND/' file`

Comment: add `/s` if you need for the dot `.` to match a newline character too. For example, to delete org logbook drawers: `perl -00 -pe 's/:LOGBOOK:.*?:END://sgi' file.org`

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile people are suggesting nice solutions, I came up with alternative solution using `sed`

```
sed '/^START/N;/^START.*END$/d' file
```

Or as suggested by *@jthill*

```
sed '/^START/N; /\nEND$/d' file
```

Comment: `sed '/^START/N; /\nEND$/d'`  
   
Need the `\n` on the second pattern or you'll trip on body lines ending `END`.

Comment: @jthill thanks for you suggestion. that works well. Added to ans. I couldn't reproduce your issue with my command, may be I don't have such scenario in my file.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
perl -ne 'print /^START/?do{$x=<>;$_,$x if $x!~/^END/}:$_' inFile
```

Output on your dataset:

```
Header


Any contents

START arguments
...
something
...
END

Footer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^START/ {
    startline=$0

    next
}

/^END$/ && startline {
    startline=""
    next
}

startline {
    print startline
}

startline=""

1
```

Comment: +1. works well on sample data. but would fail on any orphan START or END lines without pair.

Comment: What should the behaviour be in those cases? My answer would include orphan START lines (and everything after them) and would drop orphan END lines (but nothing else) I believe. The behaviour gets more complicated if their are multiples I suppose.

Comment: those cases should not be deleted.

Comment: I added a `&& startline` guard to the END pattern. That improves the stray END case and might fix the stray START problem too. I suppose you could also add backup NR checking in the END block for that too.

Comment: That works well. thanks! Sure will play around with it to match any other desired constraints.

Comment: Don't use getline for this, it introduces a ton of baggage and caveats for no obvious benefit. See awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: In this case next does the same job as far as I can see so that's simple enough to do. And while I wasn't aware of all the caveats I do, in general, avoid getline.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{ gsub(/START[^\n]*\nEND\n/,"",rec); printf "%s", rec }' file
Header


Any contents

START arguments
...
something
...
END

Footer
```